# How to set responsive width on a Sign in with Google (GSI) button with context

Tags: css, google-signin

I added Sign in with Google button from https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/personalized-button

The default style fills whole width and looks OK:
[image]

But if you have an account, it shows it in the context:
[image]

This context adds `width` to the element style inside of the iframe. I know that by spec Google button should be within 40-400px range. I wanted to make the page container `max-width: 400px`, but this button simply doesn't scale together with container.

Do I have to use JavaScript, to update the `data-width` property or is there a normal solution with CSS?

```
  <div class="g_id_signin" data-width="400" />
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Hack

I used `data-width="328"` and matched the container to have `max-width: 328px`

328px with padding can fit on a 360px phone screen (Moto G4, iPhone 6).

```html
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  ...
  <div class="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-50 py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
    <div class="w-full space-y-8" style="max-width: 328px">
      <div class="flex flex-col gap-2">
        <div
          id="g_id_onload"
          class="w-full"
          style="display: none"
          :data-client_id="clientID"
          data-callback="handleGoogleCallback"
          data-auto_prompt="false"
          data-auto_select="true"
        />
        <div
          class="g_id_signin w-full"
          data-type="standard"
          data-size="large"
          data-theme="outline"
          data-shape="rectangular"
          data-text="continue_with"
          data-logo_alignment="center"
          data-width="328"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

### Proper Solution

Wait for Google to update their library. Don't expect it to happen soon.

Comment: could you share your whole solution, e.g HTML for the button and surrounding elements? I've been pulling my hair out since the button renders at 0 height and the Google guide offers no help

Comment: I added my code which used tailwind, but the important part is `style="max-width: 328px"` and `data-width="328"` @ocramz

Comment: thank you very much @Crow. By chance, is this static or dynamically-generated HTML? Specifically, is the section with the G buttons static ?

Comment: happy to report that by using your snippet I got it to render. Previously I was using Bulma CSS which has a default behaviour with empty `<div>`s which I couldn't understand.

Comment: Ok but what if you're using the javascript API? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69250282/googles-sign-in-button-resizes-after-loading

Answer (score 3):

Using Javascript you can just re-render this button over and over.

CSS:

```
#googleSignIn {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
let googleSignInContainer = $("#googleSignIn");
let renderGoogleTimeout = 0;

window.addEventListener("resize", e => {
    clearTimeout(renderGoogleTimeout);
    renderGoogleTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        googleSignInContainer.html("");   // clear contents of Google button container
        
        let w = googleSignInContainer.width(); // get current container's width
        google.accounts.id.renderButton(
            googleSignInContainer[0],
            {
                theme: "outline",
                width: w,
            }
        );
    }, 100);
})
```

Comment: I love this solution, here's a version without jquery:

function createGSIButton(container) {
  window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(container, {
    type: "button",
    width: container.getBoundingClientRect().width,
    size: "large"
  })
}

let renderGoogleTimeout = 0;

window.addEventListener("resize", (event) => {
      clearTimeout(renderGoogleTimeout);
      renderGoogleTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        pcButtonEditorLogin.innerHTML = ""
        createGSIButton(pcButtonEditorLogin)
      })
    })

Answer (score 1):

Create a parent element with desired width, then set the parent element width to the button like bellow.

```html
<div id="parentElement">
  <button id="buttonDiv" />
</div>
```

```js
google.accounts.id.renderButton(
  document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),{ 
    theme: "outline", 
    size: "large",
    width: document.getElementById("parentElement")?.offsetWidth // Here
}
```