# Google's sign in button resizes after loading

Tags: reactjs, google-signin, google-identity

I am following https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button#javascript to add Google sign-in to my ReactJS app.

I added

```
 <script>
      function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
        console.log("Encoded JWT ID token: " + response.credential);
      }

      window.onload = function () {
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
          client_id: "YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID",
          callback: handleCredentialResponse,
        });
        google.accounts.id.renderButton(
          document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),
          { theme: "filled_blue", size: "large", shape: "pill" } // customization attributes
        );
        google.accounts.id.prompt(); // also display the One Tap dialog
      };
</script>
```

in `index.html`, and in my component, I have a `<div id="buttonDiv"></div>`.

However, this is what happens when I reload the page:

[image]

The initial button loaded is correct, but somehow is resized. I paused the JS execution in the debugger and found out that the initial button was purely `div`s, but after resizing, it used an `iframe` instead.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I have the same problem man. I can't for the life of me keep the button's size the same...

Comment: This is a really annoying issue that currently doesn't seem to have a solution. I guess the only thing we can do is wait for Google to (hopefully) update their API. It's ridiculous that in this day and age you can't set a responsive width on their sign in button.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. I reported it issuetracker.google.com/issues/227685551 . The fact that initially the width is correct but then it changes is telling. Maybe if a lot of people complain they will look into it. My guess is that since the old api is still up and running, nobody bothered to report this.

Comment: Damn it I was hoping some CSS guru could find a solution to this.  The only reason this can't be solved is because I can't change the css inside the iframe...

Comment: It seems like the whole button and the text refreshes and/or resizes after loading.

Answer (score 9):

I finally discovered the issue. The problem happens if you set the width as a float instead of an integer. For example

```
google.accounts.id.renderButton(
   document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),
   { type: "standard", theme: "filled_blue", size: "large", shape: "rectangular", width: "350.043", logo_alignment: "left" } // customization attributes
);
```

will cause the button's width to resize.

However,

```
google.accounts.id.renderButton(
       document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),
       { type: "standard", theme: "filled_blue", size: "large", shape: "rectangular", width: "350", logo_alignment: "left" } // customization attributes
    );
```

will not.

Comment: Yes, this is the complete answear to this... 8 hours untill i found your post... In my case i wanted to make the button responsive with calcualting the width of another element and pass it dinamically to the width property, but i didn't realize that the value wast always an integer.

Comment: And I'm still banned from posting new questions. Oh mighty gods of StackOverflow, what do I need to do to regain my rights? 3 likes on an answer isn't enough? T_T

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resize it to the div's size as below,

```js
document.getElementById("GoogleSignInButton"),
{
  type: "standard",
  theme: "outline",
  size: "large",
  width: document.getElementById("GoogleSignInButton").offsetWidth,
  height: document.getElementById("GoogleSignInButton").offsetHeight,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After a good hour or two of searching, I realized that the Google Identity Kit is just lacking in customization features for the sign in button.

Instead, I opted to use the old OAuth2 API, which allows you to use your own signin button HTML.

**Note: This will be deprecated as of 30 April 2022, but will be usable up until 31 March 2023 for existing apps.**

Hopefully by that time Google will have updated their Identity Kit version with more customization options.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button

Comment: The width is one of the customization features available, but it doesn't work.

Comment: By the looks of it they did not. Appearently having the worst oauth library is not a set back for google.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use your own backend server to create a fully customisable login button (Your server is used to access auth APIs instead of Google Server). As an example you can check the flow and source code for this implementation https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-google

While I'm waiting for backend update, to avoid the deprecation I used GSI... In vuejs I created a component with template:

```html
    <div
      id="g_id_onload"
      :data-client_id="GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID"
      data-context="use"
      data-ux_mode="popup"
      data-callback="handleGoogleIdentityResponse"
      data-nonce=""
      data-auto_prompt="false"
    />

    <div
      class="g_id_signin"
      data-type="standard"
      data-shape="rectangular"
      data-theme="outline"
      data-text="continue_with"
      data-size="large"
      data-logo_alignment="left"
      data-width="260"
    />
```

And a hook:

```js
function created() {
    const googleSignInAPI = document.createElement('script')
    googleSignInAPI.setAttribute(
      'src',
      'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client'
    )
    document.head.appendChild(googleSignInAPI)

    window.handleGoogleIdentityResponse = function(props) {
      const { credential } = props
      // do anything you want with the token
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For those using the button generator from the [configurator](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/tools/configurator).
Be sure not to set units in the "Custom width" field.
For a 400 px width, the attribute must be `data-width="400"` not `data-width="400px"`.

Answer (score 0):

make id of buttonDiv in CSS full with instead of width auto that's initial from browser and it will fix i think.

```
#buttonDiv{width : 100% !important;}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the button inside the iframe? Not possible, I can't change the css inside the iframe...

Comment: oh you're talking about the parent div. No, that didn't work.

Comment: Which browsers are you testing with ?