# Sign in with Google - Customize button appearance

Tags: javascript, google-signin

Using the new [JS client library for Sign in with Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web), I can't find a way to start a sign-in flow without rendering the button, and the button can't be customized enough to align with the aesthetics of the site.

Is there any way to trigger the auth flow without the button? For example:

```
// instead of:
window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(divRef.current, {
        theme: 'outline',
        size: 'large',
        width: divRef.current.clientWidth,
        text: 'continue_with',
      });

// I want something like:
window.google.accounts.id.authenticate();
```

Comment: you can't do that, since the button renders inside of an iframe

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [new authorization code flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#authorization_code_flow_examples).

```
      var client;
      function initClient() {
        client = google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
          client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
          scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
          ux_mode: 'popup',
          callback: (response) => {
            var code_receiver_uri = 'YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_CODE_ENDPOINT_URI',
            // Send auth code to your backend platform
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', code_receiver_uri, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
            xhr.onload = function() {
              console.log('Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
            };
            xhr.send('code=' + response.code);
            // After receipt, the code is exchanged for an access token and
            // refresh token, and the platform then updates this web app
            // running in user's browser with the requested calendar info.
          },
        });
      }
      function getAuthCode() {
        // Request authorization code and obtain user consent
          client.requestCode();
      }
```

And then on your customized button you can do

```
    <button onclick="getAuthCode();">Super flashy custom button</button>
```

As far as I can tell, you can't customize the button provided to you in the new Sign in with Google library but if you're doing something like `grantOfflineAccess` this is a much easier way to migrate. I'm surprised the [Google migration docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration) didn't offer this solution.

As of right now you have 3 weeks to finish the migration you procrastinator so get going :)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, user's must press a button to begin sign-in. However, you might want to check out Automatic sign-in by setting `auto_select: true` in `google.accounts.id.initialize()`. For returning users, this feature will automatically sign them in after a small delay to allow the user to cancel sign-in. This can help avoid the need for a button press and might be useful to avoid nagging users to sign-in when visiting multiple deep links within your site.

Comment: I want to trigger the popup when they click the button, I don't want it happening automatically. Basically I want to be able to adjust the button appearance, and when the users click the button, I call the SDK to initiate the sign in.

Comment: Adding a sign-in button as you describe is straight-forward, follow the [Display the Sign In With Google button](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button) guide to add it using either HTML or JS, then use the custom visual data attributes to modify the button design to suit. This will require users to click to begin the sign-in authentication process and a popup or redirect to perform the sign-in itself.

Comment: The problem is that the button can't be customized enough, for example we can't make the button have a specified hight or width. The width is capped at 400px, and there is no hight adjustments at all as far as I can tell. There is no way to customize the border-radius either, or the color of the border.

Comment: Right. A consistent look/feel and flow for users across the web takes priority over per site customization in the SDK. If the icon or standard types or colors really don't suit your needs the other option is to create a custom sign in solution flow and buttons and make direct calls to Google's OpenID or OAuth2 endpoints; both approaches are outlined on the Google Identity developer site. Essentially, you'll re-implement the SDK but be able to tune the border color and radius to meet your needs.

Comment: such behavior was straightforward when using the old gapi. Plus, by the looks of it, gapi was smaller. That's a failure that google ships such restricted in functionality SDK given its size.

Comment: Does anybody know how to fix this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69250282/googles-sign-in-button-resizes-after-loading ?

Comment: My biggest issue is that the library does not respect the width that you set. Anybody knows how to fix this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69250282/googles-sign-in-button-resizes-after-loading

Answer (score -1):

use google.accounts.id.prompt()